# Regular Expression for Specific pattern with grouping based on length

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression for a maximum of 20 characters in a group of 6 characters each separated by "-" i.e. ABCD12-DEFG34-HIJK89 in this pattern only.

so it should contain 3 groups of 6 alphanumeric characters separated by "-" and last group should contain only 6 characters.
Tried below regular expression
`^[A-Z0-9-]{20}$` but this only makes the regular expression to have alpha numeric character and "-" with max length of 20 characters.
and then I tried `^([A-Z0-9]-{7})+([A-Z0-9]-{7})+([A-Z0-9]{6}){20}$` which is not working

is there a possibility to create regex with specific pattern?

Comment: If you say 6, use 6,  `^[A-Z0-9]{6}-[A-Z0-9]{6}-[A-Z0-9]{6}$`, or `^[A-Z0-9]{6}(?:-[A-Z0-9]{6}){2}$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "spelled out" regex like

```
^[A-Z0-9]{6}-[A-Z0-9]{6}-[A-Z0-9]{6}$
```

Or,

```
^[A-Z0-9]{6}(?:-[A-Z0-9]{6}){2}$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z0-9]{6}` - six ASCII uppercase letters or digits
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `-`  - a hyphen
  - `[A-Z0-9]{6}` - six ASCII uppercase letters or digits
- `){2}` - end of the non-capturing group, repeated twice
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n0NzOX/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5BA-Z0-9%5D%7B6%7D(%3F%3A-%5BA-Z0-9%5D%7B6%7D)%7B2%7D%24):

[image]